# factory_bot define attributes method_missing dynamically or statically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory, factory-bot

When i use factory_bot_rails(6.1.0) and i have defined attributes as statically got this error,

```
 gems/factory_bot-6.1.0/lib/factory_bot/definition_proxy.rb:99:in `method_missing': undefined method 'apply_as' in 'apply_as_agent' factory (NoMethodError) Did you mean? 'apply_as { :agent }''
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have replaced factory_bot_rails with gem 'factory_bot', '~> 4.11', '>= 4.11.1' in Gemfile.
>
> It works for me...!
> [Reference Link](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/deprecating-static-attributes-in-factory_bot-4-11)